# A measure of degree of correlation for a specific two-dimensional distribution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Consider you have a complex valued function that is possible to represent in the following form:
$$ \Psi(x_1, x_2) = \sum\limits_{j} \lambda_j \psi_j(x_1) \psi_j(x_2) + \sum\limits_k \sigma_k \phi_k(|x_1-x_2|) \xi_k(x_<) , $$
where $x_<$ is the smallest of $x_1, x_2$. As this is complex-valued, only $|\Psi(x_1, x_2)|^2$ is an actual probability distribution with $\int \int |\Psi(x_1, x_2)|^2 dx_1 dx_2= 1$, $\lambda_j, \sigma_k$ are real numbers (but the functions $\phi_j, \phi_k, \xi_k$ can be complex valued in general).

My question is the following: how to introduce a continuous measure that gives $0$ if $\Psi(x_1, x_2)$ contains only terms of the first sum, where the variables are independent, and $1$ if it contains only the "correlated" terms? Please, note, that it doesn't seem to be the covariance for the obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling, I think, I have finally found a proper measure, which is called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation

This measure is just better than a regular covariance as it is always positive, and between $0$ (uncorrelated variables), and $1$ (strongly correlated variables).

Comment: Update: even though this measure is somewhat useful, it only states some "dependency" of the random variables, not necessarily of the kind suggested by me above ($|x_1-x_2|$). So, if there will be a better idea on that, I would happily accept it as an answer.